# Can someone help me convert this cocos2d-iphone specific code to be compatible with the cocos2d-mac template?

Tags: macos, templates, cocos2d-iphone

This code is used by sprites on the scene so they can be dragged.  I am having trouble trying to figure out how to convert this code to be compatible with the cocos2d-mac template. I appreciate any help.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////properties for touches moved
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {       
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);    
    [self panForTranslation:translation];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "CGPoint oldMouseLocation_;" ivar into your class.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {       
    /* snip */
}

#elif defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED)

- (BOOL)ccMouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertEventToGL:event];
    CGPoint mouseLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:point];

    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(mouseLocation, oldMouseLocation_);    
    [self panForTranslation:translation];    

    oldMouseLocation_ = mouseLocation;
}

#endif
```

Comment: I'm receiving 'oldMouseLocation" was not declared in scope.  Thank you for this, but do you think you could help me out with this error.